# How to Map oracle datatype SYS.XMLTYPE in Nhiberbate

Tags: nhibernate, .net-3.5, mapping, xmltype

I have a table in oracle having column of datatType SYS.XMLTYPE and have to map it in  Nhibernate hbm to retrieve the XML. I am using C# with .net framework 3.5 is there any specific dataType available to map this or can i use byte[] or char[] for mapping?

Thanks

Arvind

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach would involve creating an N[Hibernate UserType](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom), although you might be able to get read only access using a formula approach and mapping as a clob type.

There is an [example of doing this in Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/405.html) that might be easy to port across to .net (see also [this forum post](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=975502) and [this blog post](http://www.rialight.com/?p=15))

Generally I find it useful to search for solutions to these kind of problems using a keyword of "Hibernate" as well as "NHibernate" for these issues as the solutions are often easily portable to NHibernate

Answer (score 1):

use XMLDOC...it works like charm